# Update parent model total as new child created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a package model which has_many sales.

I'd like to sum up all the sales revenue and update the package model's total_revenue after each new sale.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an [active record callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). I would probably use `after_create`. You can add code like this:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  after_create :update_package_revenue

  def update_package_revenue
    package.update(total_revenue: package.sales.sum(:revenue)) # substitute the correct code here
  end
end
```

This allows you to run code every time you create a new sale.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic way to accomplish this would be with a setup like:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales

  def calculate_and_update_total_revenue
    update_attributes(:total_revenue, sales.sum(:revenue))
  end
end


class Sales < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  after_create :update_parent_package

  private

  def update_parent_package
    package.calculate_and_update_total_revenue
  end
end
```

It gives you a *race-condition resistan* method to bump the total (you could just add a `+self.revenue` for each new sale, but then you'd be modifying a global state from multiple execution contexts.

Still, if you write logic like this you'll end up with fat models, really hard to manage in a big application.

What about using mediator objects instead?